# Errorbar-plot with error range taken from multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, errorbar

I have a dataframe ("mean") and a dictionary containing multiple dataframes ("diff_to_mean"). I want to plot "mean" with the index-column as x-axis and "Parameter" as corresponding y-values.
From the diff_to_mean dictionary I want to create errorbars with the error-range taken from each index position.
For instance: the y-value "-6.535" should have a errorbar range from "-0.325" to "0.495".
I tried getting the max, min values with ravel() but ended up with two list, which I'm not able to combine and use as "y_error".

I would highly appreciate your help!

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def minimal():
        mean = pd.DataFrame(data={
               "Parameter" : [0, -6.535, -1.380, 1.398, -4.875] 
        })

        diff_to_mean = {
        "A": pd.DataFrame(data={
                "Parameter": [0, -0.325, -0.100, 0.310, -0.125]
        }),
        "B": pd.DataFrame(data={
                "Parameter": [0, -0.325, 0.120, 0.310, -0.025]
        }),
        "C": pd.DataFrame(data={
                "Parameter": [0, 0.155, 0.160, -0.430, -0.225]
        }),
        "D": pd.DataFrame(data={
                "Parameter": [0, 0.495, -0.180, -0.190, 0.375]
        })
        }

        y_error = []

        mX = []
        mI = []

        for df in diff_to_mean.items():
                v = df.values.ravel()
                mX.append(np.max(v))
                mI.append(np.min(v))
 
        #plt.errorbar(mean.index.values, mean["Parameter"], yerr=y_error)
        #plt.show()

minimal()
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def minimal():
        mean = pd.DataFrame(data={
               "Parameter" : [0, -6.535, -1.380, 1.398, -4.875] 
        })

        diff_to_mean = {
        "A": pd.DataFrame(data={
                "Parameter": [0, -0.325, -0.100, 0.310, -0.125]
        }),
        "B": pd.DataFrame(data={
                "Parameter": [0, -0.325, 0.120, 0.310, -0.025]
        }),
        "C": pd.DataFrame(data={
                "Parameter": [0, 0.155, 0.160, -0.430, -0.225]
        }),
        "D": pd.DataFrame(data={
                "Parameter": [0, 0.495, -0.180, -0.190, 0.375]
        })
        }

        y_error = [ diff_to_mean[x]["Parameter"] for x in diff_to_mean.keys() ]

       
        error = abs(np.max(y_error, axis=0)) + abs(np.min(y_error, axis=0))

        #print(error)
        
        plt.errorbar(mean.index.values, mean["Parameter"], yerr=error)
        plt.show()

minimal()
```

Is there a more pythonic way?

**UPDATE:**
I found out, that my solution is wrong since it creates a symmetrical error-range. I changed the line:

```
error = abs(np.max(y_error, axis=0)) + abs(np.min(y_error, axis=0))
```

to:

```
 error = [abs(np.min(y_error, axis=0)), abs(np.max(y_error, axis=0))]
```

which creates an asymmetrical range.